# Error while injecting JNDI datasources for JUnit Tests outside of a container

Tags: java, spring, junit, jndi

While writing test classes for DAO classes, i am injecting JNDI datasources for Junit tests outside of a container using the following code:

```
SharedPoolDataSource dataSource;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpDataSource() throws Exception {
    try {
        SimpleNamingContextBuilder builder = new SimpleNamingContextBuilder();
        DriverAdapterCPDS cpds = new DriverAdapterCPDS();
        cpds.setDriver("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        cpds.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxx:1521:xxxxx");
        cpds.setUser("myUsername");
        cpds.setPassword("myPass");

        dataSource = new SharedPoolDataSource();
        dataSource.setConnectionPoolDataSource(cpds);
        dataSource.setMaxActive(10);
        dataSource.setMaxWait(50);
        builder.bind("jboss/datasources/myDatasource", dataSource);
        builder.activate();
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    dataSource.close();
}
```

As you can notice, i have a `tearDownAfterClass()` method that closes the datasource after the tests are executed.

I have multiple DAO classes for which i have written test classes. In every test class i have written the same `setUpDataSource()` & `tearDownAfterClass()` to create and close datasource.

The tests run fine when run individually. But, when run together, the first test class runs successfully but the successive test classes fail with `IllegalStateException: Pool not open`.

This issue doesn't occur if i don't call `datasource.close()` in the test classes. I do not have much knowledge of `Datasource` pools, but is it the expected behaviour? If i have closed a datasource and i am creating the datasource again, why does it says that the pool isn't open?

Comment: This is the behavior as expected, at least I would expect it. You have a single shared JNDI tree, so as soon as you close something it will be closed for everyone. Basically the registration is happening once not each time you execute the bind method (as you might expect) this has to do with the underlying structure used.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Deinum. I am now using a TestSuite and closing the datsource as the last thing after executing all test classes. This works but i was just curious to know if there's way to register datasource everytime bind method is executed.

Comment: No not really because activate checks if there is already a context. Next to that internally (deep down in the jvm) there is a single JNDI register. Also do you really want to register a JNDI datasource, you might want to consider for a testcase to override the default datasource behavior and simply register a datasource in your application context.

Comment: JNDI for unit tests is a problem because you don't want to have to run the app server in order to test a class.  Better to inject in a non-JNDI data source.